# define replacing with 0s

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

So, I'm writing a relatively simple script to take a trapezoidal approximation of an integral. I had it returning results pretty easily, but giving the wrong answers. While troubleshooting that a lot of my preprocessor definitions started putting zeros everywhere.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <sstream>
    #include <cmath>

    #define PI 3.141592
    #define SLICES 25
    #define FORMULA sqrt(1+sinh(x)*sinh(x))
    #define DELTA_X (UPPERBOUND-LOWERBOUND)/SLICES
    #define LOWERBOUND 0
    #define UPPERBOUND 3

    using namespace std;

    int i=0;
    double x;
    double y[SLICES];
    double length=0;

    int main() {


    x=LOWERBOUND;

    cout << DELTA_X << endl;

    while(i<SLICES+1) { //Preparing y values to calculate in next FOR loop




    y[i] = FORMULA;


    i++;
    x+=(DELTA_X);
    cout << "x" << i << " is " << x << endl;
    }

    for(i=0;i<SLICES;i++) {

       double s = (DELTA_X)*(y[i]+y[i+1])/2;


       length+=s; 

        cout << "Length" << i+1 << " is " << s << endl; 
       }



        cout << "The approximate integral sliced " << SLICES << " times is: " << length << endl;


        return 0;
        }
```

The output basically shows all the x values, length values, and DELTA_X as 0 when printed. I had changed the formula and a couple other small things when it suddenly just started printing 0s, so I tried to change it back, but no luck. I initially thought it was because I was trying to "nest" define statements (even though it was working) so I tried just replacing them with standard integers. Same result. Any clue what I am doing.

Comment: Try replacing your macros with constants and functions.

Comment: My guess is that the compiler interprets the values int your macros as integers. Try replacing 0 to 0.0, 3 to 3.0 and 25 to 25.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the other answers tell you how to fix your macros, usually the more convenient way is to throw the macros away and replace them by constant values and inline functions:

```
static const double   PI         = 3.141592;
static const unsigned SLICES     = 25;
static const double   LOWERBOUND = 0;
static const double   UPPERBOUND = 3;
static const double   DELTA_X    = (UPPERBOUND-LOWERBOUND)/SLICES;
```

That's still doing the same for everything, right? However, `UPPERBOUND` and `LOWERBOUND` are now doubles, and (3-0)/25 won't result in 0 anymore, which was the reason for your 0 error. For `FORMULA`, use a inline function instead:

```
inline double FORMULA(double x){
    return sqrt(1+sinh(x)*sinh(x))
}
```

Note that you will need to fix your occurences of `FORMULA` in this case, e.g.

```
y[i] = FORMULA(x);
```

Comment: I hadn't considered it. Thanks for the tip! I probably will, since the preprocessor seems to have a high disposition to weird behavior if you're not careful. Script is up and running though, so this modification is next!

Answer (score 1):

```
#define SLICES 25
#define DELTA_X (UPPERBOUND-LOWERBOUND)/SLICES
#define LOWERBOUND 0
#define UPPERBOUND 3
```

Note that `DELTA_X` is replaced as `(3-0)/25`, which equals to 0 since it's integer division.

You should redefine `DELTA_X` as

```
#define DELTA_X ((double)((UPPERBOUND)-(LOWERBOUND))/(SLICES))
```

Answer (score 1):

Variables used by DELTA_X must be float

```
#define LOWERBOUND 0.0f
#define UPPERBOUND 3.0f
```

otherwise DELTA_X is always 0.

Comment: The x variable in the question that these macros end up used for, indirectly, is double, so why did you use float in your answer instead of that?

Comment: Memory saving purpose ... constants 0.0 and 3.0 (without any flags) are obviously correct (default type for floating-point literals is double).